# how to access environment variables from self hosted runner in github action

Tags: amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions, cicd

I am running EC2 as self hosted runner. I have exported AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to the EC2, and I can see that they are set with `printenv` command.

Reason for doing this is that I dont want to save AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in github secret.

Is there any way I can access and use the environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) in my github action workflow?

Comment: Please show what your current workflow yaml looks like and what you've tried

Comment: I added an official answer in this other thread with a test I made using a EC2 instance for self-hosted runner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179099/self-hosted-environment-variables-not-available-to-github-actions/71212906#71212906

Answer (score 0):

In GitHub Actions, when using a self-hosted runner, you can access environment variables just like you would on any other system. The process depends on the scripting or programming language you are using in your workflow.

Here are examples in different scripting/programming languages:

1. Bash script:
   name: Access Environment Variables

on:
push:
branches:
- main

jobs:
access-environment-variables:
runs-on: self-hosted

```
steps:
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Access Environment Variables
  run: |
    echo "MY_ENV_VARIABLE=${MY_ENV_VARIABLE}"
```

2. PowerShell script:

name: Access Environment Variables

on:
push:
branches:
- main

jobs:
access-environment-variables:
runs-on: self-hosted

```
steps:
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Access Environment Variables
  run: |
    Write-Host "MY_ENV_VARIABLE=$env:MY_ENV_VARIABLE"
```

3. Python script:
   name: Access Environment Variables

on:
push:
branches:
- main

jobs:
access-environment-variables:
runs-on: self-hosted

```
steps:
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Access Environment Variables
  run: |
    import os
    print(f"MY_ENV_VARIABLE={os.environ['MY_ENV_VARIABLE']}")
```

Remember to replace MY_ENV_VARIABLE with the actual name of the environment variable you want to access.

If the environment variable is a secret, you can access it using the secrets context in GitHub Actions. For example:
name: Access Secret

on:
push:
branches:
- main

jobs:
access-secret:
runs-on: self-hosted

```
steps:
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Access Secret
  run: |
    echo "MY_SECRET=${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}"
```