# Self hosted environment variables not available to Github actions

Tags: continuous-integration, environment-variables, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

When running Github actions on a self hosted runner machine, how do I access existing custom environment variables that have been set on the machine, in my Github action .yaml script?

I have set those variables and restarted the runner virtual machine several times, but they are not accessible using the $VAR syntax in my script.

Comment: Where have you set those variables? And have you restarted the runner after setting the variables?

Comment: @jessehouwing Yes, that is elementary, the runner EC2 virtual machine has been restarted several times.

Comment: Does the `run: env` command print the $VAR on the console when you execute it inside your self-hosted runner? (Workflow [example](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/46-print-env.yml) and [run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5253088347?check_suite_focus=true) on github runners). If yes, did you try using `${{ env.VAR }}`?

Comment: @GuiFalourd `run: env` does not show all the env variables. `${{ env.VAR }}` also does not access it

Comment: How did you set the environment variable?

Comment: @jessehouwing in /etc/environment file

Comment: Have you tried setting them with a script in `/etc/profile.d/`?

Answer (score 9):

Inside the application directory of the runner, there is a `.env` file, where you can put all variables for jobs running on this runner instance.

For example

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
TEST_VAR=Test!
```

Every time `.env` changes, restart the runner (assuming running as service)

```
sudo ./svc.sh stop
sudo ./svc.sh start
```

Test by printing the variable

[image]

Comment: This is a useful solution as well. I had run across the .env file in the docs at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/using-a-proxy-server-with-self-hosted-runners#using-a-env-file-to-set-the-proxy-configuration but didn't know it could be used for variables beyond the proxy.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a variable **only for one run**, you can add an `export` command when you configure the self-hosted runner on the Github repository, before running the `./run.sh` command:

**Example (linux) with a `TEST` variable:**

```sh
# Create the runner and start the configuration experience
$ ./config.sh --url https://github.com/owner/repo --token ABCDEFG123456
# Add new variable
$ export TEST="MY_VALUE"
# Last step, run it!
$ ./run.sh
```

That way, you will be able to access the variable by using `$TEST`, and it will also appear when running `env`:

```yaml
  job:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - run: env
      - run: echo $VAR
```

[image]

---

If you want to set a variable **permanently**, you can add a file to the `etc/profile.d/<filename>.sh`, as suggested by @frennky above, but you will also have to update the shell for it be aware of the new env variables, **each time**, before running the `./run.sh` command:

**Example (linux) with a `HTTP_PROXY` variable:**

```sh
# Create the runner and start the configuration experience
$ ./config.sh --url https://github.com/owner/repo --token ABCDEFG123456
# Create new profile http_proxy.sh file
$ sudo touch /etc/profile.d/http_proxy.sh
# Update the http_proxy.sh file
$ sudo vi /etc/profile.d/http_proxy.sh
# Add manually new line in the http_proxy.sh file
$ export HTTP_PROXY=http://my.proxy:8080
# Save the changes (:wq)
# Update the shell
$ bash
# Last step, run it!
$ ./run.sh
```

That way, you will also be able to access the variable by using `$HTTP_PROXY`, and it will also appear when running `env`, the same way as above.

```yaml
  job:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - run: env
      - run: echo $HTTP_PROXY
      - run: |
          cd $HOME
          pwd
          cd ../..
          cat etc/profile.d/http_proxy.sh
```

*The `etc/profile.d/<filename>.sh` will persist, but remember that you will have **to update the shell** each time you want to start the runner, before executing `./run.sh` command. At least that is how it worked with the EC2 instance I used for this test.*

[image]

[Reference](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shebang (the top line) in `runsvc.sh` to `#!/bin/bash --login` to ensure the shell picks up any environment variables you may have configured in `.profile`